# Is it possible to export a list to .txt such that line breakes can be read by notepad?

Tags: python, windows

For accessability reasons I wonder it is possible, in python, to export a list to .txt such that line breaks can be read by notepad? Below is an example code that is read correctly in notepad++ but not in notepad. In notepad++ each entry of the list is on a separate line, in notepad all entries are on the same line.

```
string =['str1 123','str2 234','str3 345']
outF = open("outp.txt", "w")
for item in string:
    outF.write("%s\n" % item)
outF.close()
```

Comment: Try using `outF.write('%s\r\n' %item)` instead,.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows uses **C**arriage **R**eturn, **L**ine **F**eed: `\r\n` to indicate line breaks, which is the only line-ending recognized by Windows notepad:

```
In [7]: s = ['hello', 'world']

In [8]: with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     for item in s:
   ...:         f.write('%s\r\n' % item)
```

Example:

[image]

Linux based systems use **L**ine **F**eed to indicate line breaks, and old Mac OS's used to use just **C**arriage **R**eturn, and an editor like Notepad++ can be configured to recognize all of these, while notepad cannot.

Answer (score 1):

I'll flesh out the comment's answer a little bit. Windows only recognizes carriage returns as valid points to make a new line. Therefore, it is best practice to use both carriage return and newline when making a line break in text.

So do:

```
outF.write("%s\r\n" % item)
```